# Counting groups but skipping empty in Stata

Tags: stata

My data looks like this

```
clear
input str5 name long id str3 place byte count str5 name_label byte(counting counting_ideal)
"Steve" 110821105 "ABC" 1 "Steve" 1 1
"Steve" 110821105 "ABC" 1 "Steve" 1 1
"Steve" 110821105 "ABC" 1 "Steve" 1 1
"Steve" 110821105 "ABC" 1 "Steve" 1 1
"Steve" 110821105 "ABC" 1 "Steve" 1 1
"Steve" 110821105 "ABC" 1 "Steve" 1 1
"Jeff"  110711108 "ABC" 0 ""      2 .
"Jeff"  110711114 "ABC" 0 ""      3 .
"Jeff"  110711104 "ABC" 0 ""      4 .
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Jess"  110712102 "ABC" 1 "Jess"  5 2
"Matt"  110712101 "ABC" 1 "Matt"  6 3
"Matt"  110712101 "ABC" 1 "Matt"  6 3
"Matt"  110712101 "ABC" 1 "Matt"  6 3
"Matt"  110712101 "ABC" 1 "Matt"  6 3
"Matt"  110712101 "ABC" 1 "Matt"  6 3
"Matt"  110712101 "ABC" 1 "Matt"  6 3
"Matt"  110712101 "ABC" 1 "Matt"  6 3
end
```

How can I generate the `counting_ideal` column? Note that I have several `place` variables, so that the command I'm after should specify `place=="ABC"`.

I tried:

```
encode name if count>0 & place=="ABC", gen(counting)
```

..but this generates a continuous count that does not ignore empty "name_label" observations.

Comment: Thanks for the data example. The `[CODE]`and `[/CODE]` mark-up is needed on Statalist but not elsewhere: the help for `dataex` (SSC) discusses this small detail.

Comment: The detail about "several" `place` variables isn't at all clear. I see only one such variable. Perhaps you mean that the one `place` variable has several distinct values in the full dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Given your (welcome) data example

```
gen wanted = cond(name_label == "", ., sum(name_label != name_label[_n-1] & name_label != ""))
```

Deconstruction in pseudocode:

```
if name_label is empty { 
   return missing 
} 
else return the count of runs of name_labels so far
```

Here a run is just a sequence of identical non-missing values. Hence we identify the new name label that starts a run by the condition that it differs from the previous name label (and is not empty):

```
name_label != name_label[_n-1] & name_label != ""
```

That is a true or false expression, evaluated as 1 or 0. The cumulative sum produced by `sum()` is increased by 1 when it meets a 1 and otherwise remains unchanged when it meets a 0, which is exactly what counting is.

The principles behind working with such runs or spells are discussed [in this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0029).

Your stipulation about a `place` variable isn't really explained, but if you want numbering separately for different values of `place`, then the whole operation should be done

```
gen long obs = _n 
bysort place (obs): gen wanted = ...
```